# почему union (int) выводит только только часть (char)

Tags: c++, структуры-данных, объединение

```
union c
{
    int in;
    char ch;
};
c un;
un.in = 6;
un.ch = '4';

std::cout <<un.in<< std::endl; //выведет 52
```

Почему выведется 52? Ведь мы изначально записали в объединение число 6 ,а потом 4(char) и получается у нас 1 байт должен содержать число 52(0x34) а остальные 3 байта остаток от того что мы записывали туда заранее 6(int),то есть теперь в объединении должно содержаться число 0x34'00'00'06

Comment: Потому что младший байт идет на вашей платформе первым, а не последним...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Потому что младший байт идет на вашей платформе первым, а не последним... И когда вы записали число 6 - то оно легло так:

```
0x06  0x00  0x00  0x00
```

а после того, как записали `'4'` -

```
0x34  0x00  0x00  0x00
```

Вот оно и выводит вам ваше 52, как просили :)

Вот, посмотрите, как это все работает: https://ideone.com/tUFgBX

А вообще-то, если я не ошибаюсь, то считается, что записывать в `union` одно поле , а читать другое - строго говоря, UB. Хотя *на практике* все обычно работает - если понимать, что делаешь...

*"По-моему, так" (с) Пух*

Comment: ну даже если записывается как вы показали,то получается размер char=4 байта у вас

Comment: Почему же? 1 байт. Он и перезаписан. Вот размер `union` - да, четыре байта. Первый байт - общий и для `char`, и для `int`. Для `int` - это младший байт.

Comment: Так, кто поставил минус - поясните, в чем я неправ? Или просто мишка на аватаре не нравится? :)

Comment: @Whitehorse У всех элементов `union`а одинаковый адрес, поэтому запись в `char` (который занимает один байт), может менять только этот первый байт `union`а.

Comment: никак все равно не могу понять,ведь старший бит считается концом(грубо говоря), то при записи 1 байта(char) он и будет считаться старшим(для 1 байта) и должен записаться в конец.Будем считать что у меня little indian и все байты пишутся с конца

Comment: Давайте не будем считать, а проверим... запустите у себя эту программку и посмотрите, что получится - https://ideone.com/tUFgBX  Биты *не являются* **адресуемыми**, так что где какой бит - сказать нельзя. В отличие от байтов...

Comment: @Whitehorse "старший бит считается концом" Биты тут не при чем. Вы даже не можете определить порядок бит в байтах (потому что указатели не могут показывать на отдельные биты, а только на целые байты), только порядок самих байт в типах размером больше байта.

Comment: я оговорился,я имел ввиду байты

Comment: вот исправленный вопрос: никак все равно не могу понять,ведь старший байт считается концом(грубо говоря), то при записи 1 байта(char) он и будет считаться старшим(для 1 байта) и должен записаться в конец.У меня little indian и все байты пишутся с конца.Я проверил ваш код и все так же.Но вопрос остается актуальным

Comment: Ну смотрите - union начинается с какого-то адреса. Идея его в том, что **все его поля** начинаются с этого адреса. Все - в одном месте. Значит, `int` занимает 4 байта - начиная с младшего и с возрастанием адресов - до старшего. char занимает 1 (один) байт - и он располагается именно по тому же адресу, что и первый (в нашем случае - младший!) байт int'а. Так понятнее? char - ОДИН байт, а запись начинается с начала, с наименьшего *адреса*. Вы пытаетесь идти от старшего байта, а идти надо от младшего. Измените свою логику с char'ом - смотрите, где будет записан его **младший** байт.

Comment: @Whitehorse Посмотрите на это с обратной стороны. Единственный байт `char`-а - одновременно первый и последний. Противоречие видите?

Comment: Я понял,меня очень сильно запутало little indian, я думал если меняется порядок бит,то и порядок адресации меняется...

Comment: И получается что на little indian и big indian результат таких операций может быть разный?

Comment: Да. Именно. И вообще, как я писал, в стандарте сказано, что то, что записали - то и читайте :) Иначе - UB...

Answer (score 2):

Здесь у вас неопределенное поведение, потому что вы читаете из члена юниона, который был записан НЕ последним. Если убрать последнюю запись, то всё будет ок:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <ostream>

union c
{
    int in;
    char ch;
};

int main() {
    c un;
    un.in = 6;
    // un.ch = '4';

    std::cout <<un.in<< std::endl; //выведет 6
}
```

Либо читайте последнюю запись, соответственно:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <ostream>
    
union c
{
    int in;
    char ch;
};
    
int main() {
    c un;
    un.in = 6;
    un.ch = '4';
   
    std::cout <<un.ch<< std::endl; //выведет 4
}
```

А вообще, в C++ лучше использовать `std::variant`:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <variant>
    
int main() {
    std::variant<int, char> c;
    c = 6;
    c = '4';
   
    std::cout << std::get<char>(c) << '\n'; // OK
    // std::cout << std::get<int>(c) << '\n'; // исключение
}
```

Comment: За что минус ответу?